# how to stop system startup apps (like update-notifier, evolution*, etc.) to start at login

Tags: gnome, startup, evolution, 22.10, update-notifier

Using "startup applications" I can remove MY installed apps from the startup. But there are some system apps like update-notifier, evolution-addressbook-factory, evolution-alarm-notify (and some other evolution apps), etc. which are started up automatically and are not present in the "startup applications" list. Considering that I know what they do and I don't want them to to do that at the startup, is there any way to stop them run at the login?
Ubuntu 22.10, Gnome 43.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a therminal type the code below and press enter:

```
sudo sed -i "s/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g" /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

Then you'll be able to see all startup apps that are hidden by default and you can choose which you want to disable.

Answer (score 1):

You can see which services run on start up by checking the output of

```
sudo systemctl --all list-unit-files --type=service
```

Those that the state shows `enabled` will run on start up, there will be a lot, but they are mostly necessary.

You will see three possible states, `enabled`, `disabled` and `static`. You can't directly disable static services, because they are needed by some other process. However, according to some users there is a work-around to disable them, which is by masking those services so systemd ignores them.

In order to disable services configured to run on start up you need to issue the following command:

```
sudo systemctl disable [service]
```

More info on how to "disable" a static service [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172735) and [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=147964).

OUTDATED SystemD guide in Ubuntu's [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd) or [here](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-and-using-systemd/).